# How to add an external library, Java Spring MVC framework using Gradle, PyramidIO

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I'm having trouble with adding an external library, PyramidIO, to a Java Spring MVC program. It's my first project using these.

The GitHub page for PyramidIO shows how to add it through a repository using Maven. I'm using Gradle, and this is what I did:

gradle.build

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('gov.nist.isg:pyramidio')
    compile ('org.webjars:jquery:2.1.4')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
}
```

I'm not sure if this works or not, because I can't figure out how to import it in the project. I've tried a few statements. Here's what I have now:

import gov.nist.isg.pyramido.*;

I'm not a big fan of using repositories because sometimes I work without an internet connection. I thought about simply adding the .jar for PyramidIO, but I can't find it in the GitHub download and I'm not sure how to properly compile it into a .jar.

How should I get this library into my project?

Comment: I figured out how to add another third party library, but this one still doesn't work. Eclipse complains that gov cannot be resolved. I've refreshed Gradle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download the `pyramidio-cli-[version].jar` from releases project page on [github](https://github.com/NIST-ISG/pyramidio/releases). Then you've downloaded it, you can place it under your project path and add it as dependency, like:

```
dependencies {
   compile files('libs/pyramidio-cli-0.0.3.jar')
}
```

and then, the import will be resolved

```
import gov.nist.isg.pyramidio.*;
```

Just to be clear, it could be usefull to know, that you don't have to worry about the internet connection, while you're using the repositories. Gradle has a local dependencies cache, so once dowloaded library will be available off-line and project could be build, until new dependency is provided.

Comment: I created a 'libs' folder in the root of my project and added the dependency and import statements. This seems to have fixed the issue from the perspective of the eclipse IDE, however when I try to compile it says there are errors. Under the Problems tab I have this: 

"Description Resource Path Location Type Project 'J2' is missing required library: 'C:\eclipse\unresolved dependency - gov.nist.isg pyramidio' J2  Build path Build Path Problem"

I've refreshed Gradle, and the project. This is odd.

Comment: OK, I think I figured it out. With all my fooling around, I managed to get two entries for the library in Eclipse's build path manager things. Thanks for the assistance Stanislav.

Comment: @horseatingweeds you're welcome, glad that you've found the solution. That is the reason, I prefer to use a gradle as the only build tool in order to prevent such a things from IDE. Don't know, what about Eclipse at the moment, but with Idea it's possible